# useEffect not working when dependency value changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have experienced useEffect function from React hook. When I use it with useSelector from React-redux, it worked so weird.

#### My reducer:

```
const initialState = { a: 0 };

function mainReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case 'A': return { ...state, a: payload }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

#### My Component:

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
  const { a } = useSelector(state => state.mainReducer);
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('did mount: ', a);
    dispatch({ type: 'A', payload: 1 })
  }, []); 

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('use effect: ', a);
    dispatch({ type: 'A', payload: a });
  }, [a]) 

  return (<View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>{a}</Text>
  </View>);
};
```

#### Result

Log:

```
did mount ran: 0
useEffect ran: 0
```

The last result is variable 'a'  = 0

#### ????

As I understand,
After the first render, both effect ran sequentially in their order in the code.
(Step 1) So the first effect run fist -> log 'did mount ran: 0'. Then it dispatch value 1 to store
(Step 2) The second effect run after -> log 'did mount ran: 0'. Then it dispatch value 0 to store

But what I don't understand is the second effect must track the change from variable 'a', so there will be:
In the following render time:
(Step 3) the second useEffect should be run when the value 'a' change from 0 to 1 (from Step 1).
And then:
(Step 4) it should have the third re-render when the value change again from 1 to 0 (from Step 2)

So the log should be:

```
did mount ran: 0
useEffect ran: 0
useEffect ran: 1
useEffect ran: 0
```

Could you please explain to me what I'm missing? Thank you

Comment: `useSelector(state => state.mainReducer);` !? back to learning redux

Comment: ```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export default combineReducers({
  mainReducer
});
```

Comment: I have this also @xadm

Comment: what should be in selector?

Comment: use proper selector and change order of useEffects - it should work as expected (in some sense - react for redux store changes, not amount of changes)

Answer (score 5):

Your both dispatch are called after first render so even before your second render value is 0 so your second useEffect won't be able detect change as there is no change.

Let's see what is happening in your render method

**First Render:**

*a = 0*

first useEffect: dispatch({ a : 1 })

second useEffect: dispatch({ a : 0 })

so now in your redux store a is 0.

**Second Render**

*a = 0*

first useEffect: doesn't run as there is no dependency

second useEffect: doesn't run as a hasn't changed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me. But I still have a question, when I dispatch the action 'did mount', it should update the store immediately that would lead to re-render, and this action can be reject when the second useEffect dispatch after, before the store change ?

Comment: your 'did mount' effect has changed redux store to 1 so react should re-render your component but before that there is a pending task which is to run another useEffect so react will first run that effect before rendering your component.

Answer (score 1):

## PLEASE, stop using

```
 useSelector(state => state.mainReducer);
```

it doesn't make any sense

there should be a simple state transformation (subselection)

```
const a = useSelector(state => state.a)
```

taken directly from redux docs:

```
const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter)
```

## update

you can see effect (from store change) with slightly changed component

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  const a = useSelector(state => state.a);
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); 

  console.log('render: ', a);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('use effect: ', a);
    dispatch({ type: 'A', payload: a });
  }, [a]) 

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('did mount: ', a);
    dispatch({ type: 'A', payload: 1 })
  }, []); 

  return (<View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>{a}</Text>
  </View>);
};
```

It should result in log:

- `render: 0`  // initial state
- `use effect: 0`  // first effect run
- // dispatch `0` ... processed in store by reducer but results in the same state ...
  // ... and in our rendering process we still working on an 'old' `a` readed from state on the beginning of render
- `did mount: 0` // 'old' `a`
  // dispatch `1` ... changed state in redux store
- .... rendered text `0`
  ...
  ...
- // `useSelector` forces rerendering - change detected
- `render: 1`  // latest dispatched value, processed by reducers into new state, rereaded by selector
- `use effect: 1`  // `useEffect` **works AS EXPECTED as an effect of `a` change**
- .... rendered text `1`

...
...

- no more rerenderings - latest dispach not changed state

Of course dispatch from other component will force update in this component ... if value will be different.

Comment: how does this answer question?

Comment: why not? selectors are function which take state as argument and return value from state so i am not sure why do you think it won't work.

Comment: reducers should not be called outside store AT ALL ... you should operate on state only by dispatch and reading state .... it's like using reducer in mapToState ... antipattern for me

Comment: maybe you got confused by name. in his redux store he has key with name mainReducer, it's not mainReducer function.

Comment: are you sure? I don't think so ... i saw this kind of 'selector' earlier - bad tutorial somwhere

Comment: see his comment `import { combineReducers } from 'redux'; export default combineReducers({ mainReducer }); ` so this is where he creates key name mainReducer

Comment: maybe (it shouldn't, should be private) ... still abusing redux ... you shouldn't be aware of what in the store works, one reducer or many combined ... yuo should work ONLY on results, state